# Find id while seeding data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to seed my database with a bunch of initial data for my web app. For example, there are a list of products that all have one product_type.

My `seeds.rb` has the following code:

```
ProductType.delete_all
ProductType.create(:name => 'Furniture')

Product.delete_all
Product.create(:name => 'Chair', :type_id => ProductType.first.id, :packaging => '2 for $20', :price_per => 0.1, :default_packaging_number => 2)
```

Now, my issue is that the `ProductType.first.id` is merely a placeholder. What I would really like to do is to put something like:

```
:type_id => ProductType.where(:name => "Furniture").id
```

The issue is that when I do this, **I get returned a huge number (70247318042560) that is clearly not the id**. The console also returns the warning

```
warning Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
```

When I use the `.object_id` at the end of the where statement, it still returns that same large and incorrect number.

How do I pull the id of the furniture `ProductType` from the database? Do I need to modify permissions or something to access it?

Comment: How about `ProductType.where(:name =>"Furniture").first.id` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

When you call `ProductType.where()` you're getting an ActiveRecord Relation, which is basically an array of results, even if there's only one record in that result set.

Try calling `ProductType.where(...whatever...).first.id` and see if that solves your problem.

Second, a better way:

Just save the product to a local variable.

```
ProductType.delete_all
furniture = ProductType.create(:name => 'Furniture')

Product.delete_all
Product.create(:name => 'Chair', :type => furniture, :packaging => '2 for $20', :price_per => 0.1, :default_packaging_number => 2)
```

Make sure you use the right association name (I'm guessing type...).

**NOTE** ActiveRecord already makes use of the "Type" column for polymorphic and single-table-inheritance relationships. If you're association is setup where your relationship between Products and ProductTypes is called "Type" then you may be creating a conflict, or you may risk a conflict in the future. It's best to not use that as a column name.

Why not stick with the default? If `Product belongs_to ProductType` then the default column name would be `product_type_id`

A final alternative:

If you reset your DB when you seed (probably a good idea) then you don't need to call `Product.delete_all`, the db will already be empty.

In that case you can just do `ProductType.find(1)` -- if you've just started creating records the ids will be 1, 2, 3 etc in the order you create them.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Note edit above, I accidentally left out the word "array" in the first sentence, and I added detail about the column names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just out of curiosity, you said that it should be Product belongs_to ProductType... The way that I did this was that I wrote that Product has one ProductType and that ProductType belongs to Product. Is this logic wrong? I just figured that Products would have one ProductType and belong to a Sale...

Comment: If you're doing a has_one <-> belongs_to then it doesn't really matter, but in general you setup the higher level model as "having" a lower level model, ie a category "has" an item, and an item "belongs to" a category, rather than the other way.

Comment: ...That said, I think has_one is the wrong relationship here. Is there more than one "Furniture" product? If so, that ProductType should have_many Products. Otherwise you're creating a many different ProductType:Furniture objects for any product that is associated with that type. If you don't want to a one-to-many relationship then Product Type should just be a string. If you're only using this model to store the name of the product type you're probably incurring a performance hit for no real reason.

Comment: So basically, if something is referenced by a foreign key in a 1 to many relationship, the referenced item is the has_many and the table with the referencing foreign key is the belongs_to

Comment: @jyanks: Yep. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for lots more info.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
:type_id => ProductType.where(:name => "Furniture").first.id
```

To get the id for a newly created item just go:

```
@product = Product.create(:name => 'Chair', :type_id => ProductType.first.id, :packaging => '2 for $20', :price_per => 0.1, :default_packaging_number => 2)
@product.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
:type_id => ProductType.where(:name => "Furniture").find(:select => 'id')
```